# SpringData CrudRepository applies automaticlly cascade type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

In my project I have to connect to existing database and do logic which updates two tables.

My setup is following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENTCONTENT")
@Getter
public class DocumentContent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Document document;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    @Setter
    private byte[] content;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
@Getter
public class Document {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "document")
    private DocumentContent documentContent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", fetch = EAGER)
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTACHMENT")
@Getter
public class Attachment {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Document document;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_ID",updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Contract contract;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT")
@Getter
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    @Setter
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract", fetch = EAGER)
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
}

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentContentRepository documentContentRepository; // spring data Crud Repository

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateDocumentContent(SomeDto someDto) {
        DocumentContent documentContent = documentContentRepository.findByDocumentId(someDto.getDocumentId());
        documentContent.setContent(someDto.getBytes());
        List<Contract> contracts = documentContent.getDocument().getAttachments()
                .stream().map(Attachment::getContract).collect(toList());
        contracts.forEach(contract -> contract.setStatus("SIGNED"));
        documentContentRepository.save(documentContent);
    }
}
```

When I fire method from above service I can notice those SQL in console output:

> Hibernate: update documentcontent set content=? where id=?
>   Hibernate: update contract set status=? where id=?

I understand why jpa performed first update in documentcontent table, but I don't know why it did update in contract table aswell. As you can see I didn't use `CascadeType.MERGE` in any entity.

Can you explain me why this second update has been performed without declaring cascade type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it has anything to do with Cascade at all, but with transactional write behind mechanism ([more info](https://dzone.com/articles/beginners-guide-jpahibernate-0)). I believe you could also get rid of the line

```
documentContentRepository.save(documentContent);
```

since you are modifying two managed entities. At the end of the transaction hibernate persists all entities marked as modified by the dirty checking mechanism ([more info](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/)).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 2nd query for the reason, you are modifying Status property of Contract. 
JPA detect this change and try to update entity.

This is default CaseCadeType behaviour of @OneToMany

For further reading follow this [link](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/persistence/OneToMany.java.htm).